# What’s the deal with the prefix "re-" with the Latin root "ques", "qui", and "quearere"?

Tags: etymology, latin, prefixes, derivational-morphology

The Latin root is *ques* or *qui* as seen in words like *question*, *quest*, *inquiry*, and *quiz*.  Very related to this Latin root is the root *quearere*, which seems to have a fair amount of influence on the word *require*.  The other word that jumps to my attention is *request*.

> ### **Require**
>
> verb
>   cause to be necessary. (Google)
>
> ### **Request**
>
> verb (which has been nounified)
>
> to politely ask for. (Google)

What purpose does the prefix *re-* serve here?  Seeing as both these words a derived from Latin, I would assume the *re-* prefix follow along the line of:

> back again, or again and again, or withdraw

However, *quearere* generally means to seek and *quest* means to search for something, so shouldn’t **require** loosely translate to search again, search for a long time, or stop searching?

Why is it a *request* the first time I ask for something instead of the second time I go search for something?

If I *requiz* someone, I am most certainly quizing them again.

If I make a *reinquiry*, I would undoubtedly be asking again the same as if I were to *requestion* someone.

Can someone bring some insight to the way the prefix *re-* is being used here?

Comment: If you google "request etymology", the little chart that appears for "Origin" in google's own answer box appears to offer some explanation for this.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yep, I looked.  Is it okay to ask a question I already know the answer to?  I'm hoping someone out there has a stronger understanding of this.  If I google various forms of this question, I don't get much as far as what the `re` is meaning here

Comment: If you **think** you know the answer, but have reason to doubt it, then I think that's fine as long as you explain your current understanding and the reason which you have to doubt that understanding, which you may actually do in your question (I find it a bit confusing so i'm not sure if that is the case).

Comment: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/391/asking-questions-you-know-the-answer-to possibly relevant here.  Basically, I found some answers that I'm not completely satisfied with, and feel there is probably someone out there who has a pretty strong handle on the topic.  Additionally, if I need to spend 30-45 minutes researching the topic, wouldn't it be great if the next person could find the results much quicker from this question?

Comment: If I type _define require_ into google, it tells me under origin the following: _Late Middle English: from Old French requere, from Latin requirere, from **re- (expressing intensive force)** + quaerere ‘seek’._ Does that answer your question? The use of _re-_ as an intensifier is not all that uncommon, and I'm sure can quite easily be found.

Answer (score 2):

I'm loosely translating this definition below from an italian etimologic dictionary: http://www.etimo.it/?term=ri

> re- or in its original form red- in latin is a preposition that means
>    - back (retract),
>    - against (repugnant), 
>    - renewal (recognition) 
>    - giving back (return, repay)
>    - bring to its original state (restore)
>    - put  in the right place (riporre in italian)
>    - an action that repeats (rifondere - reimburse)
>    - intensifier (redundant)
>    - pleonastic (represent)

So the -re root has quite a diverse action.

Require and request have both the same root: quearere

http://www.dizionario-latino.com/dizionario-latino-italiano.php?lemma=QUAERO100

*For some reasons the latin-english online dictionary offers only 3 definitions for this word while the latin-italian has 11, which is why I am posting italian links. I translated it to english below:*

> quearere is not only to seek but also :
>
> search, go in search   search in vain, try to find
>
> strive, aspire to, to desire, to want, to desire, seek, attempt to obtain
>
> get, obtain, procure, make, buy, win, earn
>
> (of inanimate objects) request require
>
> try to stir up, to try to do, make, run
>
> search, investigate, examine, consider, discuss
>
> ask, question, inquire, question, try to know
>
> process, make a judicial inquiry, instructing a process
>
> ask someone
>
> make a living